# How can I select the first specific class after element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count the characters of the content in textarea and show it at the below in a specific class.

I'm using the code below which doesn't work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".messageText").each(function(){
            $(this).next(".messageCharacters").text($(this).val().length);
            $(this).next(".messagePages").text(($(this).val().length / 70).toFixed());
        });
        $(".messageText").keyup(function(){
            $(this).next(".messageCharacters").text($(this).val().length);
            $(this).next(".messagePages").text(($(this).val().length / 70).toFixed());
        });
    });
</script>

<p>
    <textarea name="title1" class="messageText">phrase1</textarea>
    <br /><span class="messageCharacters">0</span> characters - <span class="messagePages">0</span> pages
</p>
<p>
    <textarea name="title2" class="messageText">phrase2</textarea>
    <br /><span class="messageCharacters">0</span> characters - <span class="messagePages">0</span> pages
</p>
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: Just out of curiosity... `($(this).val().length/70).toFixed()` when should exactly pages be counted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `$(".messageText").keyup(function(){` is outside the `document.ready` function, therefore your `.messageText` element are not collected by the DOM parser.

Also `.next()` element is `<br>` so either you need to target a parent container or do a `.nextAll()` like:

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready shorthand

  function count() {
    $(this).nextAll(".messageCharacters").text(this.value.length);
    $(this).nextAll(".messagePages").text((this.value.length/70).toFixed());
  }

  $(".messageText").each(count).on("input", count);

});
```

to prevent one copy-pasteing text inside your textarea (using mouse right click - *paste*) and your script doing nothing use `.on("input")` to register any change inside the textarea value listener.

Also think about `($(this).val().length/70).toFixed()` if initially 34 characters makes it `pages=2` only at 105 you'll get `pages=3`. So review that math again.

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/yevoro/3/edit)***

Answer (score 2):

The element next to your `.messageText` is the `br`, so `$(this).next(".messageCharacters")` will never return your element.

Use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/) instead :

```
$(this).nextAll(".messageCharacters")
```

Comment: But, there are some other textareas with the same classes, doesn't it make any problem to use nextAll ?

Comment: Depend what you mean by *"problems"*, but since `nextAll` only look for siblings and your textareas have different parents, it shouldn't cause any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change **$(this).next** to **$(this).siblings**